# how to show images in php page from link saved in DB

Tags: php, mysql, image

So if you feel the question is repeated ,I have tried other solutions but not working.I have link of images stored in Database(phpMyAdmin) as string.I want to load the image as a part of the second column of a table from DB using the links.

```
<table style="width:100%" id="to1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Featured Image</th> 
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Brand Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Shipping Cost</th>
    <th>Delivery Time </th>
    <th>Delivery Distance</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "products");
    if ($conn-> connect_error){
        die("Connection Failed: ". $conn-> connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id,featured_image,title,brand_name,price,quantity,shipping_cost,delivery_time,delivery_distance from products";
    $result = $conn-> query($sql);

    if ($result-> num_rows > 0){
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
            $val = $row["featured_image"];
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"] ."</td><td>". '<img src='<?= **HERE** ?>' alt="">' ."</td><td>".$row["title"] ."</td><td>".$row["brand_name"] ."</td><td>".$row["price"] ."</td><td>".$row["quantity"] ."</td><td>".$row["shipping_cost"] ."</td><td>".$row["delivery_time"] ."</td><td>".$row["delivery_distance"] ."</td></tr>";  
        }
        echo "</table>";    
    }
    else{
        echo "0 tables";
    }

    $conn-> close();
  ?>
```

I have shown the place as here .please suggest some ways so that I can show images instead of links in the table.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEQBy.png) is what I want it to look like.

Comment: "I have tried other solutions but not working"  I'm not seeing any evidence of that in what you posted above.  `<?= **HERE** ?>` doesn't show us what you've tried, or tell us what the result was.

Comment: What are "images stored as string"? Links? Uuencoding?

Comment: As a tip, you can write `SELECT * from products` instead of writing them out one by one.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have tried just I have deleted it some where using while loops some where taking for each ,I have tried both stackoverflow answers.I only found 2 answers

Comment: @TheWelshManc I can't as there are other columns in the table as well

Comment: @JamesZ they are stored as string

Comment: binary data cannot be stored as string -- except of course with uuencoding

Comment: You can still use the code that I suggested, it won't necessarily affect things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you had quotes problems:

UPDATED:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"] ."</td><td><img src='".$row["featured_image"]."' alt=''></td><td>".$row["title"]."</td><td>".$row["brand_name"]."</td><td>".$row["price"]."</td><td>".$row["quantity"]."</td><td>".$row["shipping_cost"]."</td><td>".$row["delivery_time"]."</td><td>".$row["delivery_distance"] ."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '"></td><td>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo "
<tr>
<td>.$row["id"].</td>
<td>.<img src='$row["featured_image"]' alt="">.</td>
<td>.$row["title"].</td>
<td>.$row["brand_name"].</td>
<td>.$row["price"].</td>
<td>.$row["quantity"].</td>
<td>.$row["shipping_cost"].</td>
<td>.$row["delivery_time"].</td>
<td>.$row["delivery_distance"].</td>
</tr>"
```

Try this